# Trouble with Fragment Alert Box

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am currently attempting to build a simple settings Fragment alert box.

I've built the main body of the alert box, however I've noticed that the actual Dialog method is not used. Also, this Dialog method replaced the `onCreate()` method.

How do I actually use the Dialog method? I can't seem to simply call it after I create the Dialog method because it comes up as an error.

Do I have to reference it in some XML?
If so, then which XML - the Fragment's XML or its parent Activity's XML?

The following is the code of my Dialog Fragment. I have not modified its XML as of yet.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ExceedingLimitFragment extends Fragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialogExceed (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.exceeding_limit_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.exceeding_limit_message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.exceeding_limit_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent ExceedingLimitPositiveIntent = new Intent (ExceedingLimitFragment.this.getActivity(), SettingsMenu.class);
                startActivity(ExceedingLimitPositiveIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.exceeding_limit_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am noticing some issues with the above code.
Fist:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialogExceed (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

seems wrong. You should only be calling the `super` method of the method you are overriding. In this case `onCreateDialogExceed` is your very own method so you should be calling `onCreate()` to that. The system relies in you calling those methods right after overriding them, so that it knows they have been called in the right order.

Does `ExceedingLimitFragment` need to display a `DialogFragment` or is it in fact the `DialogFragment`? If the answer is the later, make sure to extend that class instead of `Fragment`. After you do that, rename `onCreateDialogExceed()` to `onCreateDialog()`, which is going to be called by the system when the dialog actually needs to be created.

In order to display the dialog fragment you need a reference to that from your Activity or fragment and do something like:

```
new ExceedingLimitFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);
```

as in @dev.bmax 's answer

As for your title, `finish()` is a method of `Activity`. Neither Fragments or DialogFragments know about it, so it makes sense for your IDE to complain about it. In order to use it inside fragments make sure to do

```
if(isAttached(){
   getActivity.finish();
}
```

Comment: Hello again. About the first point, I have deleted the 'super' tag on the onCreate call. Is this okay? Also, on the second paragraph, the Studio states that the next class does not override its superclass. So I have left it as is. And in the final paragraph, just a question - can I use dialog.cancel() instead? Thanks!

Comment: if you override a method from Android, make sure to call `super` first before calling anything else. Have a look at the documentation of FragmentDialogs to see what onCreateDialog does and when it's created :) As for the `dialog.cancel()` question, it depends what you want to do. If you want to just dismiss the dialog, you should call `fragmentDialog.dismiss()` instead of  `dialog.cancel()`. FragmentDialogs are basically a fragment that hosts a dialog, and because of that you want the fragment to handle the dialog for you.

Answer (score 1):

public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

```
        public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
            MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .create();
        }
    }

           public void showDialog() {
                DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
                        R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);


      newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }



          public void doPositiveClick() {
                // Do stuff here.
                Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Positive click!");
            }

    public void doNegativeClick() {
        // Do stuff here.
        Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Negative click!");
    }


The activity creating this fragment may have the above methods to show the dialog and receive results from it, This is how you can define your dialog using dialog fragment and get the call backs in your project.
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please write up a brief explanation of why this is supposed to solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you subclass DialogFragment. To launch it, you instantiate the dialog fragment and call it's show method.

```
new ExceedingLimitFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);
```

Note: you should use either getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager() depending on which version of DialogFragment you subclass (android.app.DialogFragment or android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment)

Answer (score 1):

You can create method showDialog() and put this code in it.. this is how create a simple alert dialog with two options ok or cancel

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Add title ")
        .setMessage("Add some message")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

            }
         })
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
         .show();
```

hope to help you!